# How offset current and offset voltage affect output of single-ended diff amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, 741-opamp

> *The differential amplifier inside the OpAmp have offset current and offset voltage which is said to cause an output error when there is no input.*

This makes sense to me if the output of the differential amplifier is a differential one **(double-ended output)** in which each output is referenced to one another. **So that if one side is higher than the other, it will cause an offset voltage at output.**(so output is not zero anymore)

But I don't get why that also applies to diff amp inside the OpAmp that has a **single-ended output**. The output of singled-ended diff amp is referenced to ground so that if one side of diff amp is in offset compared to the other side **it won't matter since I'm getting the output in only one side** (*I think*)

This is a simplified schematic diagram of the 741 OpAmp in which the diff amp is single ended:[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287101/non-inverting-amp-bias-current-understanding-output-error/287191#287191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The output of singled-ended diff amp is referenced to ground so that
> if one side of diff amp is in offset compared to the other side*

That's incorrect. The output of an op-amp is: -

$$A_0\cdot(V_{IN+} - V_{IN-})$$

- \$A_0\$ is open-loop gain
- \$V_{IN-}\$ is inverting input voltage
- \$V_{IN+}\$ is non-inverting input voltage

And, it is how you implement the feedback and connect the input pins (\$V_{IN-}\$ and \$V_{IN+}\$) that determines where the output voltage is referenced. In the below example the output is referenced to ground by virtue of \$R_G\$ but it needn't be - the bottom connection of \$R_G\$ can go to any reasonable voltage within the positive and negative supply rails of the op-amp: -

[image]

So now you can see that \$V_{OS}\$ can add or subtract from the input signal and the output error will be \$V_{OS}\$ multiplied by the closed-loop gain.